# How to select the top 3 salaries of the department?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to solve a SQL problem online that has 2 tables as following,

**Employee** table

The Employee table holds all employees.

```
+----+-------+--------+--------------+
| Id | Name  | Sa1ary | DepartmentId |
+----+-------+--------+--------------+
|  1 | Joe   |  70000 |            1 |
|  2 | Henry |  80000 |            2 |
|  3 | Sam   |  60000 |            2 |
|  4 | Max   |  90000 |            1 |
|  5 | Janet |  69000 |            1 |
|  6 | Randy |  85000 |            1 |
+----+-------+--------+--------------+
```

**Department** table

[image]

The SQL should return the following data

[image]

I have the SQL queries as following,

```
    SELECT D.Name AS Department, E.Name AS Employee, E.Salary AS Salary 
FROM Employee E INNER JOIN Department D ON E.DepartmentId = D.Id 
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(Salary)) FROM Employee 
       WHERE DepartmentId = E.DepartmentId AND Salary > E.Salary) < 3
ORDER by E.DepartmentId, E.Salary DESC;
```

The SQL is good, but, I'm little confused about the `< 3` part. Shouldn't it be = 3 as in the question it was asked about top 3 salaries ? I appreciate an explanation of the SQL and will be helpful.

Comment: Are you sure that SQL is correct?

Comment: The SQL is correct and the problem is from Leetocde <https://leetcode.com/problems/department-top-three-salaries/>

Comment: No. You're assinging a rank to each salary. The top three are those with a rank less than or equal to 3.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it should say <=3 or <4 for it to be correct.

Comment: I tried in the leetcode with both =< 3 and < 4. It doesn't work there.

Comment: To answer your question, it's <3 because the count can return 0.  So the first 3 are 0, 1 and 2...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you added a column  `Count employees who earn more` your table would look like this

```
+----+-------+--------+--------------+-------------------------------+
| Id | Name  | Sa1ary | DepartmentId | Count employees who earn more |
+----+-------+--------+--------------+-------------------------------+
|  1 | Joe   |  70000 |            1 |    2                          |
|  2 | Henry |  80000 |            2 |    0                          |
|  3 | Sam   |  60000 |            2 |    1                          | 
|  4 | Max   |  90000 |            1 |    0                          |
|  5 | Janet |  69000 |            1 |    3                          |
|  6 | Randy |  85000 |            1 |    1                          |
+----+-------+--------+--------------+-------------------------------+
```

Then to find the top 3 per dept. your WHERE would be

```
WHERE `Count employees who earn more` < 3
```

If you had `=3` it would return the only employees that was the 4th highest

Since you don't have that column, that's what this SQL does

```
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(Salary)) FROM Employee 
       WHERE DepartmentId = E.DepartmentId AND Salary > E.Salary)
```

If you wanted to produce the table described above you could do the following

```
SELECT 
      D.Name AS Department, 
      E.Name AS Employee, 
      E.Salary AS Salary,
      Count(E2.Salary) as Count_employees_who_earn_more
FROM Employee E 
INNER JOIN Department D 
ON E.DepartmentId = D.Id 
LEFT JOIN Employee E2 ON 
    e2.DepartmentId = E.DepartmentId
    AND E2.Salary > E.Salary
GROUP BY  D.Name , 
      E.Name , 
      E.Salary
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c75705/25)

Comment: If I would like to get the table you have posted, which SQL should I write ? I think your answer is good, I'm just trying to get more sense of it.

Comment: Hi, could you explain what does E2.Salary > E.Salary do in the code? I am just learning SQL. It looks really strange.

Comment: actually shouldn't the "AND E2.Salary > E.Salary" rather be "WHERE E2.Salary > E.Salary"?

Comment: @Kathara that would covert the LEFT JOIN to an INNER JOIN and would remove the highest salaried employees. See the differences in the two results here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c75705/2066

Comment: @ConradFrix thanks for clarifying :-) I now see the difference ;-)

Answer (score 12):

I was working on the same SQL problem.

Just in case someone may need help.

Here's the answer I came up with.

```
SELECT
    dpt.Name AS Department,
    e1.Name AS Employee,
    e1.Salary AS Salary
FROM Employee AS e1
INNER JOIN Department dpt
ON e1.DepartmentID = dpt.Id
WHERE 3 > (
           SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Salary)
           FROM Employee AS e2
           WHERE e2.Salary > e1.Salary
           AND e1.DepartmentID = e2.DepartmentID
          )
ORDER BY
Department ASC,
Salary DESC;
```

1. The hard part is to get the top 3 salaries of each department. 
   I first count the **[number of employees with a higher salary]**.

   After that, I use **3 > [number of employees with a higher salary]** to keep the top 3 salaries only. (If there are more than 3 employees in top 3, which is to say some of them have the same salary, all of them will be included.)

   **Query**

   ```
   SELECT *
   FROM Employee e1
   WHERE 3 > (
              SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Salary)
              FROM Employee e2
              WHERE e2.Salary > e1.Salary
              AND e1.DepartmentID = e2.DepartmentID
             );
   ```

   **Output**

   ```
   +------+-------+--------+--------------+
   | Id   | Name  | Salary | DepartmentId |
   +------+-------+--------+--------------+
   |    1 | Joe   |  70000 |            1 |
   |    2 | Henry |  80000 |            2 |
   |    3 | Sam   |  60000 |            2 |
   |    4 | Max   |  90000 |            1 |
   |    6 | Randy |  85000 |            1 |
   +------+-------+--------+--------------+
   ```
2. Then it's the easy part. You can just join this table with Department on DepartmentID to get the department name.

   **Final Output**

   ```
   +------------+----------+--------+
   | Department | Employee | Salary |
   +------------+----------+--------+
   | IT         | Max      |  90000 |
   | IT         | Randy    |  85000 |
   | IT         | Joe      |  70000 |
   | Sales      | Henry    |  80000 |
   | Sales      | Sam      |  60000 |
   +------------+----------+--------+
   ```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by windowing function works with mysql>5.7 and all major databases supporting windowing function

```
select  dept_name, emp_name, salary from (
select d.name as dept_name, e.name as emp_name, e.salary, 
rank() over(partition by d.name order by e.salary desc) as rank_count 
from employee e, department d 
where d.id = e.dept_id) a where a.rank_count <4
```

You can change the inner join to left join if required when one table has a null key and the other one does not have the mapping key

Answer (score 0):

```
with sal_CTE as
(
 select e.Id as emp_id,
    d.Name as dept_name,
    e.Name as emp_name,
    e.Salary as emp_sal,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY d.ID Order By  e.Salary desc) as rank
 from Employee e inner join department d
 ON (e.DepartmentId = d.Id)
)

select dept_name as Department,
emp_name as Employee,
emp_sal as Salary from sal_CTE
where rank <=3
order by dept_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

### Another way of doing it:

```js
WITH table1 AS 
(
    SELECT Department.Name AS Department, Employee.Name AS Employee, Salary
    FROM Employee
    INNER JOIN Department 
    ON DepartmentId = Department.Id
),

table2 AS 
(
    SELECT * FROM ( 
                    SELECT Department, Employee, Salary, DENSE_RANK() OVER                       (PARTITION BY Department ORDER BY Salary DESC) AS rank 
                    FROM table1
                   ) t
    WHERE rank<=3 
)

SELECT Department, Employee, Salary 
FROM table2;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT 
  Department, 
  Employee, 
  Salary
  FROM 
  (

  SELECT 
  D.Name AS Department, 
  E.Name AS Employee, 
  E.Salary AS Salary,
  DENSE_RANK() OVER (
  PARTITION BY d.NAME
  ORDER BY d.name, E.SALARY DESC
  ) AS RANK

  FROM Employee E 
  INNER JOIN Department D 
  ON E.DepartmentId = D.Id
  group by d.name, e.name, e.salary
  ) 
  WHERE RANK <= 3
```

**FOR ORACLE 11G**

- Above query is using dense rank function.
- Department Top Three Salaries, solutions accepted on leetcode https://leetcode.com/problems/department-top-three-salaries/

Answer (score 0):

`dense_rank()` `works,rank()` creates a gap if you have `2 rows` with the `same salary`.

```
with  temp_tbl as (
select d.name as Department,i.name as Employee,Salary,dense_rank() over (partition by departmentid order by salary desc) as rnk
from employee i,department d
where i.departmentid=d.id)
select  Department,Employee,Salary
from temp_tbl
where rnk<4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH tbl
     AS (SELECT NAME,
                salary,
                departmentid,
                Dense_rank()
                  OVER (
                    partition BY departmentid
                    ORDER BY salary DESC) AS nums
         FROM   employee)
SELECT d.NAME   Department,
       tbl.NAME Employee,
       tbl.salary
FROM   tbl
       INNER JOIN department d
               ON tbl.departmentid = d.id
WHERE  tbl.nums <= 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Top 3 salaries across the Departments

```
select * from (
select
row_number() over(partition by Department_id order by Salary desc) as rnum, 
*
from
Employee
) tt
where
rnum <=3;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
With CTE_EMP AS 
(
Select d.Name AS Department, e.Name as Employee, e.Salary,
 ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by DepartmentId order by Salary desc) AS RowNumber
From Employee e
JOIN Department d on d.Id = e.DepartmentId
)
Select Department, Employee, Salary FROM CTE_EMP Where RowNumber <= 3
```

Answer (score -2):

```
select r.name as Department , t.name as Employee , t.salary from Department as r 
inner join
(select b.dept_id as departmentID , b.name as name , b.salary as salary from
(select a.departmentId as dept_id , a.name as name , a.salary as salary , dense_rank() over (partition by a.departmentId order by a.salary DESC) as
dense_rank' from (select departmentId , name , salary from Employee 
order by departmentID ASC , salary DESC) as a) as b
where b.dense_rank <= 3) as t
on r.id = t.departmentId
```